# Android async task progressbar not loading after returning to activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using Async Task to reload a data in my listview and setting a progress bar in my activity to show that it's loading. But the problem is that if I start a new activity and return back and the loading is not done the progress bar is not showing. How can I set the progress bar to continue loading? And I forgot to mention, after I return back to the activity the async task is not refreshing my listview too. Here is the code I'm using :

```
    public class MyCollectionsTask extends AsyncTask <Context, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... arrContext) {
        JsonCollection jsonColl = new JsonCollection();
        Log.e("","DO IN BACKGROUND");
        for(int i=0; i<arrContext.length; i++) {
                jsonColl.executeInsert(arrContext[i]);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        Log.e("","ON PROGRESS UPDATE");
        for (int i=0; i<progress.length; i++){
            progressBar.setProgress(i);
        }   
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.e("","ON CANCELLED");
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         sync.setImageResource(R.drawable.sync_icon2);
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        Log.e("","ON PRE EXECUTE");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        Log.e("","ON POST EXECUTE");
        SystemDatabaseHelper newdbHelper = new SystemDatabaseHelper(MyCollectionList.this, null, 1);
        newdbHelper.initialize(MyCollectionList.this);

        String genresSQLforID = "SELECT DISTINCT g.genre_id AS genreID, gl.title AS Title " +
               "FROM genres AS g, genre_lang AS gl " +
               "WHERE gl.genre_id = g.genre_id AND gl.lang_code ='" + langCode + "'"+" ORDER BY gl.title";
        Cursor genresCursor = newdbHelper.executeSQLQuery(genresSQLforID);
        if (genresCursor.getCount() == 0) {
           genresCursor.close();        
        } else {
           genresCursor.moveToFirst();
           GenID = Integer.parseInt(genresCursor.getString(genresCursor.getColumnIndex("genreID")));
        }
            getCollectionsForGenre(GenID);
        final SharedPreferences isLogged = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = isLogged.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("getProgBarCollection", false);
        editor.commit();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sync.setImageResource(R.drawable.sync_icon2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: In which method you are running this task? `onCreate()` or what?

Comment: I'm running this in onCreate();

Comment: I don't want to run the async task everytime, I just want to check if it's running to show the progressbar and update the listview.

Comment: Try `publishProgress()` in do in background.

Answer (score 1):

when you return back from another activity it just resume activity it dont go in onCreate method(). what you need to do is start another activity from your asyntask activity using **startActivityForResult()** and override onActivityResult method in your asyntask activity.
and in **onActivityResult()** execute the asyntask again. Better you do this in place of calling from asyntask in Onresume because in some other case also it will go in Onresume like pressing home key and going again

Comment: I don't want to run the async task again. I just want to know if it's still running when I get back to the activity and if it's running to show the progress bar until it's stop and after that to refresh the listview.

Comment: but if you are showing dialog from progress bar it will hold the UI  user will be not able to go forward from tht screen auntill dialog is finished. you should start dialog in preExecute method of the asyntask and in postUpdate method of the asyntask you should dismiss the dialog

Comment: the progress bar is not blocking the ui, it's just embedded in action bar and spinning there. the thing I want to achieve is to keep spinning it if the task is still running.

Comment: you check for the status in onActivityResult using AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING