# Android service / async task / thread

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have a little advice with one thing that I want to accomplish in my application. I want my application to sync some data over internet everytime when it starts and the idea is that I have a custom action bar which contains a circle progress bar and I want that progress bar to run when I'm downloading the data and stop running when the downloading is over. And I want to do this in all activities in my tabhost (I have 2 in my application and I want to do that in main one). I've already tried with `thread` and `async task`, but if I change the activity and return back the progress bar is not spinning, same with threads. Am I missing something or I should try with service too.

Or which is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: that's a lot of code dude, i just want to know which is the best way to accomplish this and what to use. the code i was using was working fine,but the problem is that as far as i know asynctask's lifecycle depends on the activity's lifecycle, threads are kind of similar too. If you can provide me a way to get that if a thread is running and then get the time when it's finish and do some things on finish, I'll be glad, but the idea of that question is to get suggestions which is the best way to do this.

Comment: You should be able to do this with `AsyncTask`

Comment: here is what I'm doing with Async Task : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259560/android-async-task-progressbar-not-loading-after-returning-to-activity

Answer (score 1):

You have to take care of activity lifecycles. Assuming that  you download the same data for all of your activities (like I do with highscore updates in my games) the best way (I was able to come with) is to spawn separate thread, but only once ( I use singleton object to do this, so I will not start downloading twice). When download is ready,  it fires intent so activities can know that and update UI properly.

So workflow is like this:

- resume activity
- obtain singletoin instance
- start downloading in case it is not active / necessary
- update interface showing that download is in process
  ...
- receive notofication broadcast and update UI

I'm also able to reuse this code for broadcast receiver,  so I can schedule periodic updates of highscore ( even if game not active at the moment )